# Is there a way to enable tearfree with amdgpu pro?

Tags: amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and I would like to know if there is a way to get amdgpu-pro driver to properly vsync. I have tried modifying the xorg file to look like:

```
Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "amdgpu-pro"
        MatchDriver "amdgpu"
        Driver "amdgpu"
        Option "TearFree" "on"
EndSection
```

but all that managed to do is break the graphics part all together (gdm crashed or was stuck during next boot).

Comment: look at this: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/4ee34q/how_to_install_configure_amdgpupro_beta_drivers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel very dumb, didn't notice that the default generated file is for **Section "OutputClass"**, what was needed is **Section "Device"**. It's all good now.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-tearfree.conf and containing
Code:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Card0"
Driver "amdgpu"
BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
Option "DRI3" "1"
Option "TearFree" "on"
EndSection
```

You have the same option in the open source driver too: Use the command man amdgpu to see them all. In Xfce you use the desktop compositor to prevent window tearing.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's actually `Option "DRI3" "3"`. According to http://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/amdgpu.4 this will set the level of DRI used, in ideal cases (and if Xorg supports it), we want it to be 3.

Comment: When doing this I get a "no monitors found" or something like that error on X.log, anybody knows why?

Comment: It's "DRI" "3" if the manpage is to go by  


`Option "DRI" "integer"
    Define the maximum level of DRI to enable. Valid values are 2 for DRI2 or 3 for DRI3. The default is 3 for DRI3 if the Xorg version is >= 1.18.3, otherwise 2 for DRI2.`

Comment: to get the correct BusID, run `lspci |grep VGA`, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg